# Como configurar banco de dados remoto no laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou configurando banco no Laravel 5.4, porém o mesmo encontra-se hospedado em outro servido, configurei no Navicat esta acessando normalmente, mais no Laravel não conecta.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=.........
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=banco
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql_gps
DB_HOST=192.168.1.125
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=meubanco
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=senha
```

***Database:***

```
'mysql_gps' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.1.125'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'meubanco',
            'username' =>'root',
            'password' =>  'senha',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Um dos bancos preciso rodar local e o outro remoto.

Comment: Como você está fazendo? Posta o código

Comment: Veja o arquivo database.php como está configurado.

Comment: Essa Linha quer dizer algo:

APP_ENV=local

Comment: @CarlosAlexandreRRamos essa configuração no `.env` vai funcionar somente para um banco de dados, o que realmente você precisa fazer???

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo, porém no banco remoto recebo informações a todo momento e preciso testar uns eventos, e o local e só configuração, autenticação e tudo mais

Comment: @CarlosAlexandreRRamos se pode apontar no model a determinada conexão um padrão para o seu sistema e uma de acordo com a sua necessidade e no `.env`, só pode ter uma configuração, porque uma sobreponhe a outra, já no config/database.php pode ter váris e usar em determinados model

Comment: Pode ser vou tentar, mais local do jeito que está funciona, mais mesmo assim vou tentar

Answer (score 1):

Configure o seu arquivo `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=banco
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION1=mysql_gps
DB_HOST1=192.168.1.125
DB_PORT1=3306
DB_DATABASE1=meubanco
DB_USERNAME1=root
DB_PASSWORD1=senha
```

ou seja, duas configurações, onde a diferença é o número 1, ou seja, você pode no arquivo `.env` colocar quantos quiser mas, identifique cada uma delas.

Vai no arquivo `app/config/database.php`:

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'mysql_gps' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST1', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT1', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE1', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME1', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD1', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET1', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

duas configurações também apontando para as configurações do arquivo `.env`.

**Como utilizar isso?**

Na [documentação sobre múltiplo configurações de banco](http://Using%20Multiple%20Database%20Connections), se for utilizar normal seria:

```
//conexão padrão
$users = DB::connection('mysql')->select(...);
$users = DB::select(...);
```

ou

```
//conexão remota
$users = DB::connection('mysql_gps')->select(...);
```

Se quiser criar isso dentro dos `model` [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) é só configur o `protected $connection` o nome da conexão, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Unidade extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['titulo'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_unidade';
    protected $connection = 'mysql_gps'; // configurando a conexão remota    
}
```

<sub>***Observação:*** os `models` [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) ou `DB` que não forem configurados pegam por padrão a configuração que está configurado em,`'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`.</sub>

***Referencias***

- [Using Multiple Database Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#using-multiple-database-connections)
- [Database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database)